# Passing NSMutableArray from Delegate to tableview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray

i have encountered a problem when wanting to pass a NSMutableArray from the delegate to a tableview controller and then reload it's data,
I need to do this because i have my socket in the delegate and when it receives data it returns a NSMutableArray which is supposed to be the data for the tableview, unfortunately it passes nil :(
ill show you my code :D

DELEGATE:

I have synthesized the tableviewcontroller in order to use get-set

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) DownloadsController *downloads_Controller;
```

And now for the code:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"downloads"] || [elementName isEqualToString:@"results"]){
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"downloads"]){
        NSLog(@"downloads found...  reloading table");
        downloads_Controller.downloads= xmlArray;
        NSLog(@"%@ passed from %@", self.downloads_Controller.downloads, xmlArray); // <-- first value return nil, while xmlArray displays properly
        [downloads_Controller.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
}
```

DOWNLOADS CONTROLLER:

Here i have done the same as on top, in order to use get-set

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *downloads;
```

Unfortunately this is what happens... when the parser delegate gets called in AppDelegate:

```
2010-01-06 13:43:41.770 iMule[613:20b] downloads found...  reloading table
2010-01-06 13:43:41.772 iMule[613:20b] (null) passed from ( <-- FIRST ARGUMENT NULL :(
    {
    name = joe;
    type = text;
    },
    {
    name = joe2;
    type = text;
    }
 )
```

Anyone got any suggestions???

Thanks =D

Comment: Is the socket receiving data on a different thread?

Comment: Shouldn't `downloads_Controller.downloads= xmlArray;` be `self.downloads_Controller.downloads= xmlArray;` ?  Or is that a typo?

Comment: self is preferred, but without self it will just skip the accessors, which is terrible if you're using stuff like Key Value Coding (KVC).

Comment: I have also tried self :( unfortunately the value is still (null) do you have any suggestions? why can't i pass a value from one view to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DID IT!!!
I totally forgot to connect the tableviewcontroller in IB! now everything is perfect!!!

Thanks for the answers :D